# Restoring database - Cannot access file because it is in use by another process

Tags: sql-server

I have a backup of a database from another SQL Server 2005 machine. I'm attempting to restore it to my SQL Server 2008 instance.

I have created a new database for the restore to go in to, but when attempting the restore with the following (generated by ssms):

```
RESTORE DATABASE [WendyUAT] 
FROM DISK = N'D:\wanda20130503.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Wendy' TO N'D:\databases\\WendyUAT.mdf',  
MOVE N'Wendy_log' TO N'D:\databases\\WendyUAT.ldf',  
MOVE N'sysft_WendyFti' TO N'D:\databases\\WendyUAT.WendyFti',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '32 (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'D:\databases\WendyUAT.mdf'.

As far as I can tell (using Process Explorer etc) nothing else is using the file. I've disabled real-time protection in windows defender. I just cannot understand why SQL Server thinks the file is in use as windows explorer lets me delete it with no problems so Windows doesn't seem to think it's in use.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Download LockHunter and you can easily tell if something else is locking file. The utility will unlock the file as well

Comment: @levelnis Cheers, LockHunter tells me that there are no processes locking the file. Which is what I would expect as Windows doesn't have any problem deleting the file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How are you connecting to your SQL Server in your application before running this backup? What **database** are you connecting to?

You **cannot** connect to the `WendyUAT` database and use it when you want to restore it - you'll have to explicitly use some other database, e.g. `master`, **before** running your SMO restore code

All my T-SQL restore scripts will always include:

```
USE [master]
GO 

RESTORE DATABASE [WendyUAT] ......
```

So if you run this backup from your app, make sure you explicitly connect to e.g. `master` before running this T-SQL restore script

**Update:**

Is this something you did on purpose, or might it just be a typo??

```
MOVE N'Wendy' TO N'D:\databases\\WendyUAT.mdf',  
                     *         **
                     *         *
                     *         *  two backslashes here  -why??? 
                     * only one backslash here...
```

Does it work if you use single backslashes only??

```
RESTORE DATABASE [WendyUAT] 
FROM DISK = N'D:\wanda20130503.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Wendy' TO N'D:\databases\WendyUAT.mdf',  
MOVE N'Wendy_log' TO N'D:\databases\WendyUAT.ldf',  
MOVE N'sysft_WendyFti' TO N'D:\databases\WendyUAT.WendyFti',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

Comment: I'm connected to master when I run the restore, and at the moment, no applications are connected to the WendyUAT database.  I've just also tried creating a completely new database and then restoring to that and same message.

Comment: @DavidGouge: what if you **do not** create a database beforehand?

Comment: Then the restore gets to 90% but then fails with The operating system returned the error '123(The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.)' while attempting 'OpenFile' on 'D:\databases\\WendyUAT.WendyFti\CatalogStatus.dat'.

Comment: @DavidGouge: why do you file names contain a single backslash first, and double backslashes later on?? Try to use **only** single backslashes!

Comment: Argh! Restore to a db that doesn't exist without the stupid double backslashes works fine. Thank you! :O)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.

What I did is that I just rename the Destination database to different name, then the restoration executed successfully. After the restoration, I just rename it to my desired database name.

Answer (score 1):

Try following script before restore

```
alter database DB_NAME set offline with rollback immediate;
```

and this script after restore to enable multi user

```
alter database DB_NAME set online with rollback immediate;
```

Comment: Thanks, even with the database offline I still get the same error. :/

Comment: @DavidGouge: Seems to be bit strange problem. Try using single backslash as suggested by Marc_s

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had installed **two** instances of SQL Server (2008 R2 and 2012). I had to **stop one SQL Server service** (2008 R2) from my two available SQL instances. This helped me to resolve this issue and I could restore my database.